# How do I detect a Webservice connection failure in a node-red flow

Tags: node-red, esp32

## Context

I have node-red V1.3.7 talking to an ESP32 using websockets. The ESP32 is behind a 3 dock dimmer controlling 3 lights. The ESP32 is connected to an 8 relay board that selects one of 3 dimmers and sends its output to the 3 lights. The ESP32 also has an IR reader/decoder. The websocket is used to send commands to the ESP32 which will turn on/off pins. The ESP32 also sends events and its state through the web socket for consideration by the flow. I have a memory leak in my ESP32, which I'm leaving in there to handle the ESP32 crashing and having the flow recuperate from the crash gracefully.

## Question

How can I react to the web socket loosing it's connection so that I can invoke a function node or something along those lines? I can see by the status icon of the webservice thingy set to disconnected when my ESP32 has crashed. I cannot find a way to trigger a node from the webservice getting disconnected. I added a catch node on the flow but it does not get triggered. The webservice node does not provide a message when it fails/disconnects.

### The flow

The flow has the following inputs:

- The Websocket from the ESP32 sending events(IR signal received) and status updates.
- A custom node connecting to my Firestick running adb logcat to detect the media playing state.
- A custom node connecting to my wifi router to parse DHCP events to detect humans comming in and out of the house by their phone's network presence.

So the light and dimmer selection are affected by the capture of specific IR codes read from the ESP32's IR receiver, phones comming in/out of the network, and my Firestick playing something.

Here is the [full flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq1Ns.png)

The flow keeps the state of the ESP32 pins in flow variables. The idea here is that when I detect a Websocket error, indicating my ESP32 has rebooted, I would re-send a message to the ESP32 for all the managed pins to set them back to the state of the flow before the reboot.

Everything in the flow ends up sending msgs to the **Pins** node, which bake a message for the **lrelay** node if it sees that a pin change would occur(dup filtering). After the **lrelay** has sent the change pin message, the response of the ESP32 contains the changed state of the pin, which then has the **save state** node save the flow variable for that pin state used to filter dups.

Here is how the error recup would work:
The **GET/salon/lumiere endpoint** returns a JSON for all the managed pins and their state for the ESP32:

```
[{"name":"D1O2","state":0},{"name":"D12O3","state":0},{"name":"D123OH","state":1},{"name":"entree","state":0},{"name":"salon","state":1},{"name":"cuisine","state":0}]
```

The pins/relay:
D1O2:    Dimmer 1 or 2
D12O3:   Output of D1O2 or dimmer 3
D123OH:  Output of D12O3 or the full 120V line(H for high)
salon:   Living root light on/off
entree:  Entrance lights on/off
cuisine: Kitchen light on/off

The Connect node sends a "Connect" websocket message to the ESP32, which then causes it to register node-red's websocket and establish the connection. This happens every second or so. Only the first one is considered by the ESP32, the other ones go into the cyber nothingness and kinda serve as a ping.

Every time(once per second) that happens, the getstate node calls that JSON end point to get the status of all the pins and sends that to the Pins node. The Pins node will promptly ignore those pin change requests as it only sends pin change requests to the ESP32 when it sees a change. In this replaying of it's own state to it's own damn self, no changes would ever be detected.

#### My proposed approach

Have a flow variable set when there has been a websocket error is detected. I would then not block the replaying of the change pin messages when that flow variable is set in **Pins**. That **error** flow variable would then get reset after the ESP32 has sent back a response into the **save state** node.

#### The alternate approach I'm considering but not loving

Replace the websocket node with either(in order of loving):

- A custom websocket node that usses proper error handling so that the catch node is triggered.
- Somehow use tcp request nodes to talk websocker and maybe have the opportunity to catch the connection error there, and use that apparatus in place of the native websocket.

#### The alternate approach I'm trying to stay away from

I could fix that problem in the ESP32 by having it initialize it's state on start-up by querying that /salon/lumiere endpoint and initializing the pins in that state, but I don't want to architecturally bind my ESP32 code to node-red, and more specifically, a specific node-red flow exposing a specific end-point. I know I could make it elegant by having a "Initialisation URL" parameter in my ESP32, which would not bind my code to node-red, but I'm having a hissy fit at the moment and looking to fix the issue in node-red, not the ESP32.

Comment: So try out your proposed approach and see how it works? I'm not seeing a question here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look at the status node

Comment: Sorry about the long form with the actual question hidden within. The question meant was how do I react to a web socket failure. I put a debug node on the output of the websocket node and do not get anything when there is an error. I also have a catch node and that also does not get triggered

Answer (score 0):

I was otherwise able to fix this through state parsing. One of the states being sent by the ESP32 is its uptime. I just kept a flow variable of the uptime, and when the ESP32s uptime is smaller than the flow variable, I can safely assume the thing rebooted, so I use that as my trigger.